Error in python code for soliving impulsive delay differential equations?
I am coding impulsive delay differential equation (discrete and distributed delay) in python.
But I am getting the error. Here is the code below and the error
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
from ddeint import ddeint

#parameters of impulsive sequence
number_of_impulses = 50
tau_a = 1.5
eps = tau_a/2
N_0 = 1

mu = 0.01

# Parameters for the DDE
beta_1 = 0.09
beta_2 = 0.11
beta_3 = 0.01
tau1 = 1  # Discrete delay
tau2 = 2  # Distributed delay lower bound

# Time range for the solution
#t = np.linspace(0, 20, 500)

# Define the history function for t < 0 (initial condition)
def history(t):
    return 1

# Define the DDE with mixed delays (discrete and distributed delay)
def model(Y, t, beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, tau1, tau2):
    # Y(t) represents the solution at time t
    y_t = Y(t)
    y_t_tau1 = Y(t - tau1)  # Discrete delay

    # Distributed delay integral: integrate Y(s) from t - tau2 to t
    integral_result,_ = quad(lambda s: Y(s), t - tau2, t, limit=100)
    
    # The DDE equation
    dydt = beta_1 * y_t + beta_2 * y_t_tau1 + beta_3 * integral_result
    return dydt

impulse_sequence = [0]
eta = [0]

for k in range(1,number_of_impulses+1):
    if k % N_0 == 0:
        delta_t = N_0*(tau_a - eps) + eps #k* N_0*(tau_a - eps) + eps
        eta_k = mu
    else:
        delta_t = eps
        eta_k = mu
    impulse_sequence.append(impulse_sequence[-1]+delta_t)
    eta.append(eta_k)

sol = np.zeros((0,1))
whole_t = np.zeros(0)
# Solve the DDE with impulses
for ii in range(number_of_impulses):
    t = np.linspace(impulse_sequence[ii], impulse_sequence[ii+1])
    temp_sol = ddeint(model, history, t, fargs=(beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, tau1, tau2))
    sol = np.vstack((sol, temp_sol))
    whole_t = np.hstack((whole_t, t))
    history = lambda t: eta[ii+1] * temp_sol[-1]

# Plot the solution
plt.figure()
plt.plot(whole_t, sol, label="Solution y(t)")
plt.xlabel('Time t')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.title('Solution of DDE with Mixed Delays (Discrete and Distributed)')

plt.figure()
plt.stem(impulse_sequence[1:], eta[1:], basefmt=" ")
plt.xlabel(r"$t$")
plt.ylabel(r"$\eta_k$")

plt.legend()
plt.show()

Error is:
home/rakesh/Desktop/dde_mixed.py:35: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
  integral_result,_ = quad(lambda s: Y(s), t - tau2, t, limit=100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rakesh/Desktop/dde_mixed.py", line 59, in <module>
    temp_sol = ddeint(model, history, t, fargs=(beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, tau1, tau2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ddeint/ddeint.py", line 145, in ddeint
    results = [dde_.integrate(dde_.t + dt) for dt in np.diff(tt)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ddeint/ddeint.py", line 145, in <listcomp>
    results = [dde_.integrate(dde_.t + dt) for dt in np.diff(tt)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ddeint/ddeint.py", line 68, in integrate
    self.Y.update(self.t, self.y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ddeint/ddeint.py", line 39, in update
    np.hstack([self.interpolator.y, Y2]),  # Y
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 359, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1, dtype=dtype, casting=casting)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)*/

